# Using PaypalSDK iOS Navigation color not changed in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

We are using below Paypal SDK in our project:- https://github.com/paypal/paypal-ios-sdk

For Navigation color changed we applied below solution:-

```
let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
paymentViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false 
self.navigationController?.present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But using the above solution navigation color not change.

Anyone has a solution for that then please help me.

Thank You. 
Shraddha vaishnani

Comment: That SDK is deprecated, why are you using it?

Comment: @PrestonPHX You are Right but this project too much old that's why we have not applied changes.

Comment: May be this helps: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/49

Answer (score 0):

```
let paymentViewController = PayPalPaymentViewController(payment: payment, configuration: payPalConfig, delegate: self)
paymentViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
paymentViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red 
paymentViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false 
paymentViewController.navigationController?.present(paymentViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me but your solution not working for me.if any other solutions then please help me.